# I want to replicate this with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm sorry if maybe the question it's a bit wide guys, but I've tried everything and I can't came with something to replace this (this is not mine, I'm just using it):

```
    function onlyNum(evt){

        evt = window.event;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)){
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

// this INPUT will not accept anything but numbers now.
<input type="text" id="idInput" onKeyPress="return onlyNum(event)">
```

with this:

```
    function onlyNum(evt){

    evt = window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)){
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

// this INPUT's with this event listeners will just acept numbers now.
// like this code is cleaner since you just need to make a list of ids that will have this listeners.
var input = document.getElementById('idTest');
input.addEventListener('keyDown', onlyNum, false);
```

I can't find a way to pass the event to the function and the "return" part. Sorry I don't even know how to describe it and maybe that's why I cannot find any info about this problem...

Comment: You should really be using `.preventDefault()`... it'll apply to the handler's target anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using generic event handlers with `addEventListener()` or `attacheEvent()`, you can't just `return false` to prevent the default action like you can if you put the event handler in the HTML.  Instead, you need to call `evt.preventDefault()` and perhaps `evt.stopPropagation()` in most browsers or set `window.event.returnValue = false` and `window.event.cancelBubble = true` in older versions of IE.

To do that simply and cross platform, I've developed an `addEvent()` function that does all the cross platform work for you (including IE6, IE7, IE8).  So, using that to add the event handler, all you would do is this:

```
addEvent("idTest", "keydown", onlyNum);​
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/2ATmz/.

Here's your code using the new event function:

```
function onlyNum(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

addEvent("test", "keydown", onlyNum);​
```

And, here's the cross platform event function:

```
// refined add event cross browser
function addEvent(elem, event, fn) {
    if (typeof elem === "string") {
        elem = document.getElementById(elem);
    }


    // avoid memory overhead of new anonymous functions for every event handler that's installed
    // by using local functions
    function listenHandler(e) {
        var ret = fn.apply(this, arguments);
        if (ret === false) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        return(ret);
    }

    function attachHandler() {
        // set the this pointer same as addEventListener when fn is called
        // and make sure the event is passed to the fn also so that works the same too
        var ret = fn.call(elem, window.event);   
        if (ret === false) {
            window.event.returnValue = false;
            window.event.cancelBubble = true;
        }
        return(ret);
    }

    if (elem.addEventListener) {
        elem.addEventListener(event, listenHandler, false);
    } else {
        elem.attachEvent("on" + event, attachHandler);
    }
}
```

Note: I slightly modified `onlyNum()` because this event handler function always passed the event object (you don't have to handle things differently for IE).

Comment: Thanks! works great but only if I put the addEvent("test", "keydown", onlyNum);​ at the bottom, if not I get a "cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" error, is it normal to put javascript at the end of the page or its better at the head?

Comment: You can't call `addEvent()` until the page DOM is loaded.  The simplest way to do that is to put the code in a script at the very end of the `<body>` tag.  There are other ways that involve waiting for a DOM ready event, but if you're not using a framework that does that for you in a cross browser fashion, you might as well pick the simple way and put the code at the end of the `<body>` tag.  Yes, this is normal and actually makes your page load and show faster.

Comment: Really apretiate your time and patience to explain your script. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
window.onload=function(){ 
    var input = document.getElementById('idTest');
    if(input.addEventListener) input.addEventListener('keydown', onlyNum, false);
    else input.attachEvent('onkeydown', onlyNum, false);
}

function onlyNum(e)
{
    var e=e || window.event;
    var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)){
        if(e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
        else e.returnValue = false;    
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GVKwS/).